# AS3 - Y Velocity 6.123031769111886E-17

Tags: actionscript-3, math

When given 0,0 to 0,5, the y velocity becomes that number and breaks my code. I know I must have done something wrong as I just copy and pasted code (since I am horrible at maths)..

This is how I calculate the numbers:

```
var radian = Math.atan2(listOfNodes[j].y - listOfNodes[i].y,listOfNodes[j].x - listOfNodes[i].x);
var vy = Math.cos(radian);
var vx = Math.sin(radian);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how that number breaks your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There i am assuming the velocity vector is FROM 0,0 TO 0,5. And 0,0 is i and 0,5 is j.

In that case the velocity vector is only along y and the y component should be 5 and x component 0. It is coming as opposite because,

`cos(radian)` whould be x velocity component and `sin(radian)` the y compunent.

And the number 6.123031769111886E-17 is actually returned in place of 0.

Look at the following figure:
[image]

Also as can be seen from the figure you do not need the trigonometric computations at all.
You can simply get the x and y components as follows:

```
// y2 - y1
var vy = listOfNodes[j].y - listOfNodes[i].y;
// x2 - x1
var vx = listOfNodes[j].x - listOfNodes[i].x;
```

This will avoid the floating point inaccuracy caused by the trig finctions due to which you are seeing 6.123031769111886E-17 instead of 0.
You only need to use `atan2` if you actually need the angle θ in your code.

**Update:**
Well if you need only unit (normalized) vector's components you can divide the vx and vy with the length of the original vector. Like this:

```
// y2 - y1
var vy = listOfNodes[j].y - listOfNodes[i].y;
// x2 - x1
var vx = listOfNodes[j].x - listOfNodes[i].x;
// vector magnitude
var mag = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);

// get unit vector components
vy /= mag;
vx /= mag;
```

Using the above you will get the exactly the same results as you are getting from trig `sin` and `cos` functions.

But if you still need to use the original code and want to make 6.12...E-17 compare to 0, you can use the epsilon technique for comparing floats. So you can compare any value within epsilon's range from 0, using flllowing code:

```
function floatCompare(a:Number, b:Number, epsilon:Number):Boolean{
    return (a >= (b - epsilon) && a <= (b + epsilon));
}
// To check for zero use this code, here i'm using 0.0001 as epsilon
if(floatCompare(vx, 0, 0.0001)){
    // code here
}
```

So any deviation in the range of `[b-epsilon, b+epsilon]` would successfully compare to b. This is essential in case of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't work in my situation because I need to hitTest it every step so that I know the line does not intersect another object. Is there a way so that I get 0 instead of that number?